# Clear form input after message has been sent

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im trying to clear the form message input field after the form has been sent. Although its clearing the data before it has a chance to be sent.
Here is my code:

```js
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('form#SendForm').on('submit', function (e) {
            $.post('sendmessagefriend.php', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
                // This is executed when the call to mail.php was succesful.
                // 'data' contains the response from the request
            }).error(function () {
                // This is executed when the call to mail.php failed.
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
    $('#SendForm').on('click', function () {
        $('#SendForm').find('input:text').val('');
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
    });
</script>
```

FORM:

```html
<form id="SendForm" class="SendMsg" role="form" method="post" action="sendmessagefriend.php">
 <input type="text" id="s_firstname" name="s_firstname" class="MsgInputHidden" value="<?= $_SESSION["user"]["firstname"] ?>" />
 <input type="text" id="s_lastname" name="s_lastname" class="MsgInputHidden" value="<?= $_SESSION["user"]["lastname"] ?>" />
 <input type="text" id="sender" name="sender" class="MsgInputHidden" value="<?= $_SESSION["user"]["id"] ?>" />
 <input type="text" id="r_firstname" name="r_firstname" class="MsgInputHidden"value="<?= $FriendName->firstname ?>" />
 <input type="text" id="r_lastname" name="r_lastname" class="MsgInputHidden"value="<?= $FriendName->lastname ?>" />
 <input type="text" id="recipient" name="recipient" class="MsgInputHidden" value="<?= $FriendName->id ?>" />
 <input type="text" id="ip" name="ip" class="MsgInputHidden" value="<?= $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] ?>" />
 <input type="text" id="date" name="date" class="MsgInputHidden" value="<?= date('Y-m-d') ."\n" ?>" />
 <?php $now = time(); $utc_time = $now - intval(date('Z', $now)); ?>
  <input type="text" id="time" name="time" class="MsgInputHidden" value="<?= '' . date('H:i:s', $now) . '' ?>" />
  <input id="message" type="text" name="message" style="width: 100%; overflow: scroll;">
  <input id="submit" class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: @Caspar Just a good advice for you nets post: Try to avoid a horizontal scrollbar in your post. A horizontal scrollbar makes it uncomfortable to read a text.

Comment: as you have a .error where you will handle your error, you can have a .success where you can place the code that empties the inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a click handler, put this

```
$('#SendForm').find('input:text').val(''); 
$('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

in the success callback like

```
$('form#SendForm').on('submit', function(e) {
        $.post('sendmessagefriend.php', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
            // This is executed when the call to mail.php was succesful.
            // 'data' contains the response from the request
            $('#message').val(''); 
        })
        .error(function() {
            // This is executed when the call to mail.php failed.
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

If you don't care whether the request is successful or not and just want to clear the input regardless, put it after your ajax call like

```
$('form#SendForm').on('submit', function(e) {
            $.post('sendmessagefriend.php', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
                // This is executed when the call to mail.php was succesful.
                // 'data' contains the response from the request
            })
            .error(function() {
                // This is executed when the call to mail.php failed.
            });

            $('#message').val('');  
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

Comment: It works! Although its clearing all my other fields other than message

Comment: @CasperRound, what does the HTML for the message element look like?

Comment: Ill add it to my post 1 sec